# What is the best way to filter a query using user inputs

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project that takes 4 fields from the user to filter a query coming from a mysql database.

The user enters in a date range, a name search, and/or a game result. The query can work while all fields are not filled in and must work when all fields are filled in.

I need to write a program that does all of this but the only way I can think to do this is by writing a bunch of if statements to see if the user has filled in or not filled in each individual form element. There must be a better, more efficient way of doing this.

```
<form method="post" action="extra.php">
Date Range From:
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" value=""/>
To:
<input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" value=""/>
<br/>
Name Search:
<input type="text" id="nameSearch" name="nameSearch" value=""/>
<br/>
Game Result:
<select name="gameResult">
    <option value="any">Any</option>
    <option value="p1">Player 1</option>
    <option value="p2">Player 2</option>
    <option value="draw">Draw</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>




<?php
include('../inclass/db_connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['dateFrom']) && ($_POST['dateTo']) && ($_POST['nameSearch']) && ($_POST['gameResult'])){
    $dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];
    $nameSearch = $_POST['nameSearch'];
    $gameResult = $_POST['gameResult'];

    $result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo') AND (player1 LIKE '$nameSearch%') OR (player2 LIKE '$nameSearch%') AND (result ='1') ORDER BY matchDate desc LIMIT 250");

    $result->execute();

        ?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Match Date</th>
        <th>Player 1</th>
        <th>Player 2</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>ECO Code</th>
        <th>Match Details</th>
    </tr>
<?php
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['matchDate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['player1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['player2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['result']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['eco']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="details.php" id=".$row['id'].">Details</a></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
```

http://cps276.net/zgambrell/04/extra.php

I just need some guidance in the right direction in how to accomplish this without having to write 50 if statements. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, there's no another way, just `if`s

Comment: so I need to write an individual if(isset) statement for each individual outcome that could possibly happen?

Comment: IS there a way I can put my table into a function or class, and then when I need it to be posted, instead of re-writing out the entire table over and over again I can just make a function call so I only have to write the code for the table on time?

Comment: Put the table structure in a separate file called partial (search_results_table.php) and include it only when needed in the main file.

Comment: So something like ... 
if(isset $_POST['nameSearch']){
 $nameSearch = $_POST['nameSearch'];
include(search_result_table);

$result =$pdo->prepare("SELECT matchDate, player1, player2, result, eco FROM matches WHERE (matchDate BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo') AND (player1 LIKE '$nameSearch%') OR (player2 LIKE '$nameSearch%') AND (result ='1') ORDER BY matchDate desc LIMIT 250");

    $result->execute();
}

Would that do it? or do i need to make a call for it to display the table?

Comment: Call for it to display the table with the results. require_once() or what was the old school include statement in php, I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to allow at least one of the fields to be filled in?

One way I could think of is to put all of the values into an associative array and loop through it and check if the field was empty or not.

Example:

```
// put all of the values into an array
$searchForm = [
    'dateFrom' = $_POST['dateFrom'],
    'dateTo' = $_POST['dateTo'],
    'nameSearc' = $_POST['nameSearch'],
    'gameResult' = $_POST['gameResult'],
];

// loop through the array and see if the fields are not empty
foreach($searchForm as $inputField) {
   // if the fieldsa re not empty
   if(!empty($inputField))
   {
       // put them into a new array
       $searchValues = $inputField
   }
}
// check the number of elements of the array
if(count($searchValues) === 0) {
    // return back to the page and show an error that at least one field is required.
}

// execute the query here
```

You can put this code into a function and reuse it to validate other form fields as well. Just pass the array of input fields as a parameter.

I have no idea if this will work but it should give you an idea of what you can do to cut down on the if(isset()) statements.